# NodeRed POST request to Sharepoint REST API

Tags: sharepoint-rest-api, nodejs, request-digest

I want to upload files on Sharepoint and I'm using Node Red for communicate with REST Sharepoint API.

As far as I know, first of all I need to request a diggest token for the POST communication: so, my first request was:

> https://{site_url}/_api/contextinfo

Then, with the FormDigestValue got before I think I'm able to make the post request. My msg.payload and my msg.header were this one:

```
msg.payload = {
              '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.Data.Shared_x0020_DocumentsItem' },
              'AllowContentTypes': true,
              'BaseTemplate': 100, 
              'ContentTypesEnabled': true, 
              'Description': 'My test description', 
              'Title': 'Testing',
              "UseUniquePermissions" : false
              }
              
msg.headers= {
            "X-HTTP-Method":"MERGE",
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "Cookie": msg._msgid,
            "X-RequestDigest": msg.sharepointresult.GetContextWebInformation.FormDigestValue,
            "IF-MATCH": "*"
        }
```

And the URL is these one:

> https://{site_url}/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/sites/TestcomunicaciSQLServer/Documentos%20compartidos')/Files/add(url='/home/administradorae/Test.txt',overwrite=true)

I try with POST and PUT, I try with MS Sharepoint Node and with http request Node and don't care, the result was always the same:

> "Sharepoint node error POST: StatusCodeError: 403 - {"error":{"code":"-2130575251, Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException","message":{"lang":"es-ES","value":"La validación de seguridad de esta página no es válida y podría estar dañada. Use el botón Atrás del explorador web para volver a intentar la operación."}}}"

or these one

> "{"error":{"code":"-2147024891, System.UnauthorizedAccessException","message":{"lang":"es-ES","value":"Acceso denegado. No tiene el permiso necesario para realizar esta acci\u00f3n o tener acceso a este recurso."}}}"

Someone have some idea what happens there?
Maybe I need a certificate? Or maybe I need a Bearer token? I read from internet I can do it with diggest authentication.

Thanks

Comment: I'm not exactly sure if you need something more than the form digest value from `/_api/contextinfo` (from what I know, that _should_ work). But there seems to be a disconnect between what you are specifying in the metadata of your payload (`SP.Data.Shared_x0020_DocumentsItem`, which indicates an **item**), and the other properties in your payload, which are **list settings**, not item properties (which would be column names). Also, I'm not sure if you even need a JSON payload when uploading a file. When I have uploaded files through `/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl()/files/add()`...

Comment: ...I have not included a JSON payload, just the file buffer for the file itself. And, when uploading a file using that endpoint, I never add all those headers, I only use `accept` and `X-RequestDigest`.  I have only used all those other headers (`"IF-MATCH":"*"`, `"X-HTTP-Method":"MERGE"`, etc) when _updating a list item_, which is a different operation than uploading a file.

Comment: Hi Dylan, thanks for your reply, I tried only with:
`msg.headers= {
 "X-RequestDigest":FormDigestValue,
  "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
  "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose"
}`

and 

`msg.payload = {'__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.File' },}`

and the error is the same... don't know why... if I get a solution I will post it.
Thank you

Comment: I'm not sure if your `msg.payload` is the same as the jQuery `$.ajax({ data: })` property (I think it might be), but when using jQuery `ajax()` to upload files, as I said before, I do not use a JSON payload - the payload is an `ArrayBuffer` of the file contents itself, which I get through creating a `new FileReader()` and then calling `reader.readAsArrayBuffer(fileBlob)`. If you do that, you'll probably want to remove the `content-type` header because what you are sending to the server is an `ArrayBuffer` and not JSON.